# fetching rows in big table with firedac

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I have a big table on sql server, about 800k records.

How could I navigate through all the records, x amount at a time?

For example, I would like to open FDQuery, but browse 1000 records at a time.

If I use:

```
FDQuery.First;
while not FDQuery.eof do
begin
   //do something
   FDQuery.Next;
end;
```

I believe all records are brought;

I have read about fetching records, properties like FetchOptions:
Mode, RowsetSize, RecsMax, RecsSkip ... but I can't browse all the records, a fixed number of records at a time.

Comment: sorry, it's my first question on stack overflow

Comment: If you have an ID column with regularly-spaced values, it is trivial to retrieve them a block at a time (`where ID >= low and ID <= high`), but your users will likely thank you more if you can find a natural key that will work similarly to an on-paper phone directory.  Trying to retrieve 800k rows  all at once ruins performance, not just for the user of your app but for every other user of the table as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some creativity, provide pagination and fetch let's say 100 rows per page using a thread which is equipped with a nice progress bar in the UI. in this method you must manage search and filters by some smart queries, reloading data sometimes, etc...

IF you are using SQL server one of the options could be using some ranking functions like ROW_NUMBER to fetch each page.

Something like this:

```
;WITH CTE_Test AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY F1) AS Row_No FROM Tbl_Test
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Test
    WHERE Row_No BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```